# Ember textfield events not working when using init

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to initialize my ember text field view to prefill it with the query string. But whenever i add an init function to my view all other defined events stop triggering.

How do i get my events to keep working while using initialization ?

```
App.SearchBarView = Ember.TextField.extend({
    throttle_instance: _.debounce(function(){
        var value = this.get('value');
        this.update();
    }, 1000),
    /**
    * Initialize the textbox with a set value
    */
    init: function(){
        var query = "testquery";
        if(query && query.length > 0){
            this.set('value', query[0]);
            this.get('controller').set('query', query[0]);
            this.update();
        }
    },
    insertNewline: function() {
        this.update();
    },
    /**
    * Handle the keyup event and throttle the amount of requests
    * (send after 1 second of not typing)
    */
    keyUp: function(evt) {
        this.get('controller').set('query', this.get('value'));
        this.throttle_instance();
    },
    /**
    * Update the pages results with the query
    */
    update: function(){
        var value = this.get('value');
        this.get('controller').filterByQuery(value);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `this._super()` inside your `init` method to maintain the view's default behaviour:

```
...
init: function() {
  this._super();
}
...
```

Hope it helps.